# realm.io writeCopyToPath ? what's the inverse operation?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

so I have some realm swift code:

```
   let realm = Realm()
   realm.writeCopyToPath(tempfile! , encryptionKey: nil)
   let newasset = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tempfile!, isDirectory: false))
```

and then I save off the newasset to cloudkit...

but when I bring it back,

```
   let defaultPath = Realm().path
   var someError: NSError?
   NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(defaultPath, error: &someError)
   if someError != nil {
       println("Error removing realm file, \(someError)")
   }
   NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(asset.fileURL.path!, toPath: defaultPath, error: &someError)
   if someError != nil {
       println("Error copying realm file into place, \(someError)")
   }
```

it does not seem to work... I'm wondering if there is another way to bring back the realm file and place it where realm expects it?

Answer (score 0):

The default location and file name of the default Realm file is `default.realm`, located in the app's Documents directory. As long you've correctly copied the Realm file out of CloudKit and to that location with the proper file name, accessing that file via calling `Realm()` should just work straight out of the box.

It sounds like you've got a few points in here that you can potentially test to see if anything is failing:

1) Make sure the duplicate Realm file is being created properly.
2) Ensure the file is uploaded to CloudKit properly, without fail.
3) Ensure the file came back down from CloudKit properly without any errors.
4) Double-check that copying the file from CloudKit to the default Realm file path succeeded.

If that all didn't work, please let me know here what sort of error you're specifically getting. Thanks, and good luck!